# Using the Character of a Range in Subset()/Coercing Range from Character to Numeric

Tags: r, subset

I'm struggling with having the subset() function use a range (i.e. 4:7) that is being called as a character from a variable.

Is there a way for me to coerce the input, which is the variable DayVar and has different days I want the function to subset, to be numeric while avoiding the following issues:

1.) keeping the 4:7 as such instead of as 4, 5, 6, 7, and

2.) converting the character "1:4" into numeric format that the subset evaluation can use as though it were 1:4.

Here is a sample data frame:

```
DayVar = c("1", "2", "3", "4:7")

a <- c("a", "b", "c", "d", "e", "f", "g", "h", "i", "j")
b <- c(61:70)
Day <- c(1:10)

df <- data.frame("a" = a, "b" = b, "Day" = Day)

Subset <- list()
for(i in 1:length(DayVar)){
   Subset[[i]] = subset(df, Day %in% DayVar[i])
}
```

Comment: You want to loop over a list probably - `DayVar <- list(1,2,3,4:7)`

Comment: Are you really forced to keep these values as strings? Or is there a reason you chose to store it what way?

Comment: When DayVar = c(1,2,3,4:7) it converts it to c(1,2,3,4,5,6,7), so the function extracts seven data subsets, rather than 4 (with the fourth including all of the days 4,5,6, and 7).

Answer (score 1, accepted):

As thelatemail suggested the list works but you have to change the DayVar quotes to get the list index:

```
DayVar <- list(1,2,3,4:7)

Subset <- list()
for(i in 1:length(DayVar)){
  Subset[[i]] = subset(df, Day %in% DayVar[[i]])
}
```